# Scroller for a absolute div inside a Fixed parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header on my site , inside the header i have a button that triggers a vertical category menu like amazon.com . the problem is that the categories ( or list items ) in a menu exceeds than the height of a standard viewport and if a person scrolls down to see more categories the menu div remains fixed and other content on the page scrolls, I have used over flow property to my menu div but its of no use. any solution?

```
.ma-header-container {z-index: 9999;/*background: url(../images/yay-vo/bg.png) no-repeat 100% #fff;*/padding-bottom: 25px;background-size: 100% 100%;position: fixed;left: 0;right: 0;top: 0; }
.scr-ma-header-container {border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;height: 95px;z-index: 9999;background:#fff;/*padding-bottom: 25px;*/background-size: 100% 100%;position: fixed;left: 0;right: 0;top: 0; }
```

Above css is for my Fixed header container

```
.YV-allcat {
vertical-align: top;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 15px;
color: #000;
height: 50px;
/*height: 40px;*/
width: 146px;
background-color: transparent;
border-top: 2px solid #c2c2c2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
float: left;
background: none;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
box-shadow: none;
/*background-image: url("../images/yay-vo/menu-arrow.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 110px 33px;*/
}
```

And this is the button that triggers the menu

```
.main-menu {
width: 180px;
/* margin-left: 14px; */
padding: 12px 0px;
float: left;
/* background: url(../images/left-menu-bg.png) top left repeat-y; */
position: absolute;
top: 174px;
/* top: 157px; */
/* border-right: 4px solid #565656; */
/* margin-top: 10px; */
background-color: #FFF;
z-index: 9999;
border: 1px solid #cecece;
/* min-height: 546px; */
min-height: 450px;
height: auto;
}
```

and thats the menu with exceeding number of categories, hope it helps

Comment: show us some code, how can we possibly help? Create a fiddle

Comment: @DarrenSweeney i have pasted the css .

Comment: @ZeeshanRizvi Read what DarrenSweeney posted - CREATE A FIDDLE.

Comment: @RaviH i can't create a fiddle because the menu contains dynamic content and html is very complex , you can still help if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow property was not working because i didn't gave the max- height, these two lines saved my life

```
max-height:100%;
overflow-y:auto;
```